# How to convert Keynote to PowerPoint online

Tags: ms-office, keynote

Is there a way to convert a downloaded Keynote (from slideshare) file to a PowerPoint file (or an open format like Open/LibreOffice) online?

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to convert a keynote file to a powerpoint file? Or what kind of formats are you wanting?

Comment: I wouldn't actually call Powerpoint "open"...

Comment: @patrix you're correct, I meant either open in powerpoint or open in a different "open" format such as open office.

Comment: @bcholbeisineeman Why not just open it in Keynote, click `Export` and choose ppt (PowerPoint). Obviously, transitions are lost due to compatibility, but I assume converting does not do that either.

Comment: @bcholbeisineeman DevIntern's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/134709/243377) should be the accepted answer - it is a free solution provided by the owner of the proprietary format with no limitations on file size or otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/) claims to convert Keynote files to different formats (including PowerPoint) online. I don't use Keynote, so I can't vouch for the quality of the conversions, but here's one [review](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fileextensions/gr/zamzar-file-converter.htm) of the free file conversion service.

Comment: Good find. It seems to convert Keynote files quite well -- at least as well as Powerpoint does itself: elements are separate, with editable text fields.

Comment: I just tried Zamzar and compared it with the "Export..." function in Keynote. Unfortunately, the .ppt file from Zamzar had to be "repaired" by powerpoint, resulting in the same flaws observed when exporting from .key to .ppt within Keynote. Hence, no improvement (at least for me and my keynote presentation.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how you can do this...

1. Sign in / up for iCloud at www.icloud.com
2. Open the online "Keynote" app
3. Drag your Keynote file onto the browser window
4. Keynote browser app will open your presentation
5. Make any changes etc.
6. Click the wrench icon on top right, and select "Download a copy"

[image: Click the wrench icon on top right, and select "Download a copy"]
7. Keynote will prompt you with option to download a PPT / PDF / Keynote file

[image: Keynote will prompt you with option to download a PPT / PDF / Keynote file]
8. Select PPT and ye shall receive a Powerpoint version :-)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about https://www.icloud.com/#keynote.  This was exactly what I wanted.  I was nervous about uploading my file to some other site like Zamzar.  I'm glad Apple has its own free solution. Thanks.

Comment: This is not "Here is how you can do this..." but "The only correct way to do it"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are after but this [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_998291&feature=iv&src_vid=zd6717eu_eQ&v=m78ZZGamWbE) is a video on exporting a keynote slideshow as a powerpoint presentation. There is also [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/).

Comment: thanks but i'm looking for a way to convert an already downloaded keynote (from slideshare) to ppt

Answer (score 0):

Simply Export the file out of Keynote as a Powerpoint.  It does a dang good job of maintaining the formatting.

[image]